# How can I use a global variable within a javascript if statement?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, global-variables

This is the code I've been trying to use within my visualforce page. My idea is to detect which user is using the page, and then have the javascript do something depending on who it is. The code below is a test. I don't understand why it's not working?

```
<script>
if('{!($User.FirstName)}') == 'Steve' {
document.getElementById('{!$Component.Month}').value = 'January';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Always be careful with JavaScript and first place to look at the errors in browsers developer console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were to look in your browser's Javascript console, you would see an error message along these lines:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==

You've closed your `if` evaluation early:

```
if ('Steve') == 'Steve' {
//         ^ closed early
```

should instead be:

```
if ('Steve' == 'Steve') {
//                    ^ closed appropriately
```

---

PS – In general, you shouldn't trust strings to be safe for consumption by your scripts. Make sure to escape them!

```
if ("{!JSENCODE($User.FirstName)}" == "Somebody") {
```

Or just compare within merge syntax as recommended in the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

When possible, do your comparisons in the merge field; this reduces the likelihood of making mistakes like this. Here's your if statement written using a merge comparison:

```
if({!$User.FirstName='Steve'}) {
```

Comment: Double or triple equals would be better :)

Comment: @RahulSharma It's not JavaScript inside the `{!` and `}`, it's formula syntax. In formulas, `=` and `==` are the same, and `===` does not exist in formula syntax.

Comment: Ah crap didn't noticed that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answers, yes, you can use global variables in javascript. That being said, if you want different values for different users, you should look into using the [`$Setup`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) global variable. By setting up these values in a hierarchical custom setting, you avoid hard-coding the otherwise complex list of different behaviors for each individual in your vf page, which would make it easier to maintain:

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.Month}').value = 
    '{!JSENCODE($Setup.User_Prefs__c.Month__c)}';
```

vs

```
if ("{!JSENCODE($User.FirstName)}" == "Steve") 
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.Month}').value = 'January';
else if ("{!JSENCODE($User.FirstName)}" == "Bob")
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.Month}').value = 'February';

// (you would probably want to separate this out to a function 
//    with a switch/case statement if you do it this way, but 
//    it would still be more complex than it needs to be)
```